# jquery sortable, changing sequence of items

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible to reorder the items in a sortable list without dragging them?
For example if I have a list of items, say 1,2,3, I click on a link (a button - whatever) and the list is now 3,1,2.
Maybe I shouldn't use "sortable" for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">


    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" style=""><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li><li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li><li class="ui-state-default" style=""><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" style=""><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li><li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>

</ul>
```

You can reorder list items without drag and drop by calling the following function:

```
function shuffle(){
    var myList = $('ul'); //Fetch the list.
    var listItems = myList.children('li'); //Extract all listItems from it.
    listItems.sort(function(a,b){ //This function sorts the items.
        var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        return (compA < compB) ? -1 : 1; //return a -1 or 1 depending upon specific condition.
    });
    $(myList).append(listItems);
}
```

You can invoke the function using any simple button like:

```
<button onclick="shuffle();">Reorder</button>
```

[You can see a sample implementation here.](http://jsbin.com/OTEKaWO/3/edit?html,js,output)